# How to sychronize bookmarks with Microsoft Edge?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, sync, bookmarks, microsoft-edge

Currently I am using [XMarks](https://www.xmarks.com/) to sync all my bookmarks between work and home and also the browsers Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. This works as intended. Now I want to start using Edge. I can import from Internet Explorer and have my favorites now in Edge. But when I add a new favorite to Edge this will not be synced back to the other browsers. Any solution for this?

Comment: As of today (the first of January 2016), there is no solution. Microsoft is feverishly adding features to all areas of Windows 10, and is slated to add support for extensions in early 2016. [Xmarks will have an extension ready soon after](https://buy.xmarks.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=9292). Until then, a work-around is to set your Edge home page to display your Xmarks bookmarks page: https://my.xmarks.com

Comment: Did this ever happen? I hear there is an insider build with this feature, but it's really off the mark with how long its taking to easily integrate this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This may be old news by now, but here's how I've accomplished it:
(I'm not sure if the first step is required, but it can't hurt.)

1) From the Notification button (LR corner) > All settings > Accounts > Sync your settings: Switch on the Internet Explorer Settings and whatever other Windows items you want to auto-sync.

2) (**Windows key + R**) > **gpedit.msc**

3) In the left pane, **Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Microsoft Edge**

4) In the right pane, double-click on **Keep favorites in sync between Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge**

5) Select **Enabled**, click **OK**, close the editor

Not sure if a reboot is required, but I did and it took a few minutes before IE and Edge were synced.  Favorites added and/or deleted from either IE or Edge will now auto-sync.  XMarks will continue to sync between Chrome, Firefox and IE, while the Group Policy will keep IE and Edge in sync, making all four synced.